# 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Fill' and no extension method 'Fill' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting 2 errors.

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Fill' and no extension
>   method 'Fill' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be
>   found

and

> 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no
>   extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.DataRow' could be found

Here is the code:

```
public partial class account_Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("PartNumber");
        dt.Columns.Add("Qty");
        dt.Columns.Add("Price");
        dt.Columns.Add("ExtPrice");
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        Session["DT"] = dt;
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        BindGrid();
    }
}



private void BindGrid()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = Session["DT"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
}



protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // 1off


    WebReference.WebServiceTyped ws = new WebReference.WebServiceTyped();
    WebReference.CheckPartStatus pq = new WebReference.CheckPartStatus();
    DataTable dttemp = new DataTable();
    Session["DT"] = dttemp;

    pq = ws.CheckPartNumberStatus(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, "1", "", "", "1");

    string price = pq.Parts[0].Cost.ToString();

    DataRow dr = default(DataRow);
    dr = dttemp.NewRow();
    dr["PartNumber"] = TextBox1.Text;
    dr["Qty"] = TextBox3.Text;
    dr["Price"] = price;
    dr["ExtPrice"] = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox3.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(price);
    dttemp.Rows.Add(dr);
    Session["DT"] = dttemp;
    dttemp = null;
    BindGrid();
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    WebReference.WebServiceTyped ws = new WebReference.WebServiceTyped();
    WebReference.CheckPartStatus pq = new WebReference.CheckPartStatus();

    string sql = "SELECT PartNumber, Qty FROM PackageDetail where Package_Name = 'SILVERADO4'";

    DataTable dtparts = new DataTable();

    String da = ConfigurationManager
       .ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;

    da.Fill(dtparts);

    //Dim Parts As String = "RANRS5114,RANRS5116,RANRS5118"
    //Dim strs() As String
    //strs = Parts.Split(",")

    for (int i = 0; i <= dtparts.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DataTable dttemp = new DataTable();
        Session["DT"] = dttemp;

        pq = ws.CheckPartNumberStatus(dtparts.Rows[i].Item["PartNumber"], "", "1", "", "", "1");

        string price = pq.Parts[0].Cost.ToString();

        DataRow dr = default(DataRow);
        dr = dttemp.NewRow();
        dr["PartNumber"] = dtparts.Rows[i].Item["PartNumber"];
        dr["Qty"] = dtparts.Rows[i].Item("Qty");
        dr["Price"] = price;
        dr["ExtPrice"] = dtparts.Rows[i].Item["Qty"] * Convert.ToDouble(price);
        dttemp.Rows.Add(dr);
        Session["DT"] = dttemp;
        dttemp = null;
    }
    BindGrid();
}
}
```

Would really appreciate it if someone helped me, I have tried everything to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: The error message is right. You have `da.Fill`, what exactly did you expect this to do? `da` is a string, did you mean to create a data adapter instead?

Comment: OHHH yes that is what i meant to do my fault what about the 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found

Comment: *Hint*: The error messages you get contain a line number. These numbers show exactly on which line the error occurs. Check the line number to find where your error occurs. *Hint 2*: one of your .Item calls is not like the others. The line number will tell you which one. For future reference, please include the line numbers and highlight the lines they belong to in your question. You are getting a number of low-quality answers because your question lacks details. *Hint 3*: `'(' != '['`

Comment: Thanks Hugo but i still do not understand whats wrong with dtparts.Rows[i].Item["PartNumber"]

Comment: Why do you think that the error is in that line? I rather doubt it. Have you tried looking for the line number in the error message? Knowing where your error happens is really helpful, I cannot recommend it enough. With that and my third hint, you should be able to fix this in no time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String da = ConfigurationManager
       .ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;

    da.Fill(dtparts);
```

You're trying to call the Fill method on a String object, when you want a [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill(v=vs.110).aspx) object.

Here is another example that has code for what you may be trying to do. [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
        dttemp = (DataTable)Session["DT"];
        part = (string)dtparts.Rows[i]["PartNumber"];
        qty = (string)dtparts.Rows[i]["Qty"];

        pq = ws.CheckPartNumberStatus(part, "", "1", "", "", "1");
        string price = pq.Parts[0].Cost.ToString();
        DataRow dr;
        dr = dttemp.NewRow();

        dr["PartNumber"] = dtparts.Rows[i]["PartNumber"];
        dr["Qty"] = qty;
        dr["Price"] = price;
        dr["ExtPrice"] = Convert.ToDouble(qty) * Convert.ToDouble(price);
        dttemp.Rows.Add(dr);
        Session["DT"] = dttemp;
        dttemp = null;
```